# How can I affect css,js to my project? deploy with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

This is my environment/production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
config.assets.digest = true
config.log_level = :debug
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

but I received 404 status code.

I think maybe the fingerprints of assets file from local is different from that of server.

It is strange that css,js affected correctly　two days ago.

My development env works correctly.

what happens?

please tell me.Thank you so much.

someone any idea?Plase.

Comment: Did you run `rake assets:precompile` and see `/public/assets` folder in your production environment?

Comment: I have done `rake assets:precompile` but nothing is changed.

I could solve this question to kill all data on server and deploy again... 

I don`t know why this happen.